# C++ boost serialization - how to replace type of field in archive

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

Let's say I am serializing a map into an XML archive using boost. The map is of type std::map< long, CMyObject >. I realize that I need to use this type instead: std::map< std::string, CMyObject >. How would I go about handling backward-compatibility in this case? Here's what my serialize methods look like right now:

```
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int file_version)
    {
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(m_MyMap);
    }
    void serialize ( std::ostream &out ) const
    {
        boost::archive::xml_oarchive oa ( out );
        oa << boost::serialization::make_nvp ( "MyArchive.xml", *this );
    }
    void serialize ( std::istream &in )
    {
        boost::archive::xml_iarchive ia ( in );
        ia >> boost::serialization::make_nvp ( "MyArchive.xml", *this );
    }
```

m_MyMap is currently of type std::map< long, CMyObject > but needs to changed to std::map< std::string, CMyObject >. What's the cleanest way to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

Well,
[split serialize into save/load](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html#splitting),
[bump the version](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html#versioning),
and

```
template<class Archive>
void load (Archive & ar, unsigned version) {
  if (version < 1) {
    std::map<long, CMyObject> tmp; ar & tmp;
    for (auto& en: tmp) m_MyMap[std::to_string(en.first)] = en.second;
  } else ar & m_MyMap;
}
```